# JSON Interpolation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects, string-interpolation

I have this JSON object.

it's just for example:

```
{"reportResource": {
 "linksForReport": "My name is {0}. Surname is {1}"}}
```

And I have init.js file

In init.js file i have 2 variables

```
${reference.Name()} ${reference.Surname()}
```

How to make so that instead of {0} and {1} change variables on ${reference.Name()} ${reference.Surname()} in my init.js file?

I want to just take from JSON and put my variables instead of 0 and 1

Comment: there's a nice npm package to do this kind of thing with a similar (but not identical) syntax: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache

Comment: Those two "variables" are not variables. Variables have a name and a value.

Comment: I know. Sorry for my English. I just tried to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var myObj = {"reportResource": {
 "linksForReport": "My name is {0}. Surname is {1}"}

myObj.reportResource.linksForReport.replace("{0}", reference.Name());
myObj.reportResource.linksForReport.replace("{1}", reference.Surname());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arrayForReplace = [
           `${reference.Name()}`, 
           `${reference.Surname()}`
         ]

for(let i = 0; i< 2; i++){
    reportResource
      .linksForReport
      .replace(
           `{${i}}`, 
           arrayForReplace[i]
      );
}
```